# separate a string into multiple queries

Tags: php, mysql

Lets say i have a string as so

```
$string = "12 Days Of Terror";
```

and i want to break down this string at each space and insert each word into my DB.

the table: `tags`

Columns: `movie`, `tagname`

Value: `102`, `$string`

how would you write the query for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just split the string using explode: http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php and then insert each tag in the table.